# Want to Create Tab in Ember application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I am completely new for ember mobile application.

I am trying to crate tab but i am not able to do it.

my .hbs file

```
<div class="tabpanel">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div {{action "goToFirstTab"}}>First tab</div>
      <div {{action "goToSecondTab"}}>Second tab</div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
```

I have done tab with like when i tapped on it it will go at another screen.
I need it like when i will tap on tab it should be on same screen i.e. toggling.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use nested routes for this.

So this is your router:

```
this.route('tabbing', function() {
  this.route('tab1');
  this.route('tab2');
});
```

and then in your `tabbing.hbs`:

```
<div class="tabpanel">
  <div class="tabs">
    {{#link-to 'tabbing.tab1' tagName="div"}}First tab{{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'tabbing.tab2' tagName="div"}} Second tab{{/link-to}}
  </div>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

You put the *tab content* in your subroutes. So `tab1.hbs` and `tab2.hbs`. So the content of `tabbing.hbs` will always be present and the content of tab1 and tab2 will be toggled.

Comment: Okay so i will need to add tabbing function in my js file which is in route directory?

Comment: You specify the routes in your `router.js`.

Comment: it gives me synatx error.it is not working with js file :(:(

Comment: Please help me.Will you provide me like step by step code.What i will need to add in my hbs file,js file

Comment: [You just copy that code.](https://ember-twiddle.com/88421aad0ea98fa369834cecbb03a604?openFiles=templates.tabbing.hbs%2C&route=%2Ftabbing%2Ftab1).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources & addons about implementing Tabs in Ember :

- [ivy-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ivy-tabs) addon: tabs without routing (selecting a tab does not transition to route)
- [bootstrap-for-ember](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember) addon: a (very) more complete addon with tabs support ([with](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/tabs-with-routes) and [without](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/tabs) routing)

IMHO using routes is always a best choice.

Here is also a more complete discussion about implementing Tabs with routes in Ember : http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/tabbed-ui-with-routing/7336

Hope it helps